# Umbraco 8 shows install screen after deploying on GoDaddy server

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco8

I have developed site using **Umbraco 8** and **uSkinned** theme. I am able to run in my local development environment as well as local IIS. but when I deploy it to GoDaddy it shows me install screen.
I followed below are the steps.

1. Visual Studio Publish to folder.
2. Using above published folder I hosted site to my local IIS(it works on IIS)
3. I have created backup of database
4. Restored backup to GoDaddy SQL Server. I checked after restoreing, tables and data is there on GoDaddy SQL Server(I used LinqPad).
5. I used publish output created on step 1 and updated connection string and uploaded to GoDaddy.
6. When I browse site it shows me install screen.

Why it shows me install screen even if it has data in database as well as same set of file as IIS local? What  I am missing.

Thanks for help

**Edit**

I get below logs

```
{"@t":"2021-03-24T11:50:03.7387476Z","@mt":"{EndMessage} ({Duration}ms) [Timing {TimingId}]","EndMessage":"Booted.","Duration":1592,"TimingId":"6f43df2","SourceContext":"Umbraco.Core.Runtime.CoreRuntime","ProcessId":1700,"ProcessName":"w3wp","ThreadId":29,"AppDomainId":3,"AppDomainAppId":"LMW3SVC8ROOT","MachineName":"S107-180-73-24","Log4NetLevel":"INFO ","HttpRequestNumber":1,"HttpRequestId":"75319e5f-ad35-4c7b-9aa2-fe04a05c9007"}
{"@t":"2021-03-24T11:50:04.1450357Z","@mt":"New url {Url} detected, re-discovering application url.","Url":"http://yourmodern.skinfogroup.com/umbraco","SourceContext":"Umbraco.Core.Sync.ApplicationUrlHelper","ProcessId":1700,"ProcessName":"w3wp","ThreadId":16,"AppDomainId":3,"AppDomainAppId":"LMW3SVC8ROOT","MachineName":"S107-180-73-24","Log4NetLevel":"INFO ","HttpRequestNumber":2,"HttpRequestId":"7f3c5e24-22d0-4cc8-940d-13b6e8622a9f"}
{"@t":"2021-03-24T11:50:04.1450357Z","@mt":"ApplicationUrl: {UmbracoAppUrl} (UmbracoModule request)","UmbracoAppUrl":"http://yourmodern.skinfogroup.com/umbraco","SourceContext":"Umbraco.Core.Sync.ApplicationUrlHelper","ProcessId":1700,"ProcessName":"w3wp","ThreadId":16,"AppDomainId":3,"AppDomainAppId":"LMW3SVC8ROOT","MachineName":"S107-180-73-24","Log4NetLevel":"INFO ","HttpRequestNumber":2,"HttpRequestId":"7f3c5e24-22d0-4cc8-940d-13b6e8622a9f"}
{"@t":"2021-03-24T11:50:04.5356961Z","@mt":"Umbraco must install or upgrade.","@l":"Warning","SourceContext":"Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule","ProcessId":1700,"ProcessName":"w3wp","ThreadId":16,"AppDomainId":3,"AppDomainAppId":"LMW3SVC8ROOT","MachineName":"S107-180-73-24","Log4NetLevel":"WARN ","HttpRequestNumber":2,"HttpRequestId":"7f3c5e24-22d0-4cc8-940d-13b6e8622a9f"}
```

**EDIT 2**

I validated that connection string correct. I am able to connect to the database and execute queries. I have also validated that it has same no of tables and rows.

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? These should be in `App_Data\Logs`. This behaviour is usually caused by a database connection error.

Comment: @LewisHazell updated question with logs. do I need to update anything in DB?

Comment: this happens when Umbraco is not able to connect to the database or another reason - the database is not restored correctly

check please the database and connection to the database

Answer (score 0):

This Umbraco forum thread says it could be a permissions issue: https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/102946-moving-umbraco-v8-to-new-server-fails-you-see-this-screen-because-your-umbraco-installation-did-not-complete-correctly#comment-322275 - specifically the part in there about

> changed the permissions on the server (by creating a new sql server
> user and login with the same rights)

Answer (score 0):

Heres my debuggin tips:

1. Have you upgraded?  Have you copied the DB into live, or, you using a fresh DB?
2. How are you doing your transforms? Perform a file compare between files using a tool like Beyond Compare
3. Delete contents of `Add_Data`
   Install screen can be triggered if `Umbraco.Core.ConfigurationStatus` is not populated

See this for details:
https://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-7-tutorials/umbraco-upgrading-guide/how-to-reinstall-umbraco/

Answer (score 0):

There was issues with the server. I validated this by.

1. Hosting same website on other server(works)
2. Hosting website with default data on same server(does not works).

**Edit**

Rebuilding server did not fix the issue.